# css: Header fluid height but content scrollable

Tags: css, position

I´m trying to find css a sulution for this. I have a list menu at the top of my page, below this is a div with content. the content div should always have 100% of the remaining viewport hight. the browser scrollbars should be hidden, the content div should have scrollbars. no problems until here. for this i gave the content div position:absolute and a top value.

My problem know is, if the the user resizes the browser the menu brakes to a new line, and the menu overlaps the content this because the content has a fixes "top" value.

One solution would be to read the height of the menu div on browser resize and then set the position of the content div. But I like to avoid js. My question is, can I do this with css only.

Please find an example below.

Cheers,

Tony

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head class="html5">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>test</title>

<style>
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav{
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    }

#nav ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 40px 0 0;
}   

#content{
    overflow:scroll;
    height:100%;
    top:50px;
    position: absolute;

}

#content p{height:1024px;border:1px solid red;margin:0;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

  <div id="nav">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>


  <div id="content">
    <p class="article">here goes the content</p>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserts divs `nav` and `content` inside one div, `container`:

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="nav">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
         <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div id="content">
       <p class="article">here goes the content</p>
   </div>
</div>`
```

In your CSS:

```css
#container {
   width: 1024px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
#nav {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
   height: 250px;
}
#content{
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Hi Milind, thanks for your answer. Unfortuntely the content div looses the scroll if I try your solution. What I whant is, hide the Browser scroll. have the content and menu dynamic in height if bworder resize breaks menu lines. and content always fill remainig height: thats what the css looks like with your answer. html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.Container { width:1024px; margin:0 auto;}

#nav{float:left;width:100%;height:50px;}
#nav ul li{list-style-type: none;float:left;margin: 0 40px 0 0;} 
#content{overflow: scroll;float:left;width:100%;height:100%;}

Comment: to be more precise, I only can make the content div scrollable if it´s position absolute, but the the menue overlapps the content if the height is not enough ?

Comment: then add     
     `overflow:scroll` in content div and set limit with height and width u want